# how to check innerHTML of a span in Appium?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm trying to check the innerHTML of a span in Appium.  I've tried using element.getAttribute().

here is my sample code:

```
.elementsByXPath('//span[contains(@class,"approvallistclass1")]') 
        .then(elements => {
            for (key in elements) {
                elements[key].getAttribute('innerHTML').then(attr => {
                    console.log(attr)
                });
            }
```

Comment: `elements[key].innerHTML`

Comment: that didn't work. comes back as undefined. these elements are appium element objects, not normal html elements.

Comment: for some reason, I can do elementsByXPath(...).first().getAttribute('innerHTML'). the problem was in trying to use the elements array in the .then() statement.  Apparently I don't have a firm understanding of webdriver promise chains yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin method for getting innerHTML/outerHTML. But in python you can use XML module to parse the outerHTML.

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring, fromstring
outerHTML = tostring(fromstring(generic_driver.page_source).findall('.//*[@scrollable="true"]')[0]).decode()
```